# Mysql join three tables problem

Tags: mysql, join

I'm using three mysql tables that looks like:

The table for members accounts

```
|       id     |     name    |   status   |
-------------------------------------------
|       1      |      mike   |      0     |
|       2      |      peter  |      1     |
|       3      |      john   |      1     |
|       4      |      any    |      1     |
```

The table for list of friends:

```
|    myid     |    user     |    date    |
------------------------------------------
|     10      |     2       | 2010-01-04 |
|     3       |     10      | 2010-09-05 |
|     4       |     10      | 2010-10-23 |
```

The table for users galleries:

```
|    fotoid     |    userid     |    pic1    |
------------------------------------------
|      101      |       2       |    1.jpg   |
|      102      |       3       |    2.jpg   |
|      103      |       4       |    3.jpg   |
```

I want to join this three tables and get query result which will list the users that I added to the list of friends and those who have me add to the list at the same time, all these users must have status of '1 'from the members table and display their photos from the gallery table.

In this example, my ID is '10'. In the table for the galleries field 'MyID' represents those users who have added other users to theirs friends while the 'user' is the ID of the added users.

The end result in this example should look like:

```
|    id    |   name   |   status   |    pic1   |
------------------------------------------------
|    2     |  peter   |     1      |   1.jpg   |
|    3     |  john    |     1      |   2.jpg   |
|    4     |  any     |     1      |   3.jpg   |
```

How can I do that?

mysql EXPLAIN:

```
id  |  select_type     |  table  |    type   |   possible_keys   |  key    |   key_len   |    ref    |    rows   |    extra                            
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |  primary         |   g     |   ALL     |   id              |  NULL   |   NULL      |   NULL    |   7925    |  Using where
1   |  primary         |   a     |   eg_ref  |   id              |  id     |   4         |   g.id    |   1       |  Using where
2   |DEPENDENT SUBQUERY|   a2    |   index   |   id              |  NULL   |   NULL      |   NULL    |   90734   |  Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort;
2   |DEPENDENT SUBQUERY|   f     |   index   |   rds_index       |rds_index|   8         |   NULL    |   138945  |  Using where;Using index;Using join buffer
```

Comment: If you cannot do a join why dont you learn You have here what you need http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.id, 
       a.name, 
       a.status, 
       g.pic1 
FROM   accounts a 
       JOIN galleries g 
         ON g.userid = a.id 
WHERE  a.id IN (SELECT a2.id 
                FROM   accounts a2 
                       JOIN friends f 
                         ON ( f.myid = a2.id 
                               OR f.user = a2.id ) 
                WHERE  ( f.myid = 10 
                          OR f.user = 10 ) 
                GROUP  BY a2.id) 
       and a.status = 1
```

**EDIT 1**

Let's take for now the subquery, for now loose the group by stuff:

Make sure you have indexes on these columns:

```
accounts.id
friends.myid
friends.user
```

And run this query:

```
SELECT a2.id 
FROM   accounts a2 
       JOIN friends f 
         ON f.myid = a2.id 
WHERE  f.user = 10 
UNION ALL 
SELECT a2.id 
FROM   accounts a2 
       JOIN friends f 
         ON f.user = a2.id 
WHERE  f.myid = 10
```

Then post back how long performed.

Comment: @Pentium10 - Thanks Pentium10. I tried this query but it takes more than 5 minutes and mysql server get stuck. Is there any reason why?

Comment: Show us your table schema, probably you are missing some indexes on your key columns. Also run a `explain extended` on the query and post the details.

Comment: @Pentium10 - You can see the details from mysql explain in my question. I just post that details. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please check if the subquery executed separated runs slow. And for some reason the explain extended tells that this is a dependent subquery, I don't know why tells that, make sure you don't reference any tables/columns from outside of the subquery like `accounts`

Comment: @Pentium10 - I tested the subquery and it was slow but still give a result. But when I try entire query SQL server is blocked. 

This query is intended to give customers an insight into the changing profile of people who are on their friend lists. Something similar to that on facebook.

Comment: @Pentium10 -  Is it possible to do this query in some other way?

Comment: Please see my updated question with a new subquery, and list of indexes you need for now.

Comment: @Pentium10 - This query took 0.5618 sec. If I want to include another table with the posts of users who are, just like these users, on the list of friends (table 'friends') and also have a status '1' in the table 'members', what is best way to do this?

Comment: You probably take the same subquery, and use it on the posts table. I see you need to change galleries to posts.

Comment: @Pentium10 - I can not use the existing array from an existing query with users who meet the criteria to have the status of '1' in the table accounts and are on the friends list? Or I must repeat the entire query every time when I want to get a list of topics or some other details of these users?

Comment: Hard to tell without table schema details. Maybe post another question. I soon will leave for today.